# private git - 500 Error

Tags: git, gitlab

I have private git setup on an Ubuntu server. All the projects are working great but this one is blowing my mind. I have looked for solutions but of no use. It's just when I click **Files** on the tab, no matter what branch it is, it gives me '500'.

Here are some pictures:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1lwNY_vQ5kmWHZ2V09pUDl0a0U/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1lwNY_vQ5kmLUcwRDBzSFJfQWc/view?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Click "Files" where? Where do you see this "500" message?

Comment: Can’t post answer (no information given in the question). Seriously though, it’s hard to tell what you’re even doing and what your setup is. Provide more information; and you *can* upload pictures elsewhere (although you should still try to explain everything in words).